# shape_diagonal_direction not found even though I did

Tags: android, android-layout

Following is my simple `xml` layout file after I implement `ShapeOfView` library from `Github`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:shape_diagonal_angle="6"
    app:shape_diagonal_direction="right"
    app:shape_diagonal_position="bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/homepage" />
</com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>
```

but when I debug it, I get this error:

```
Android resource linking failed
/home/.../fragment_home.xml:9: error: attribute shape_diagonal_direction not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Why is that?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be such an attribute, at least in the latest version: https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView/blob/master/shapeofview/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#L21. Also, looking at the source for `DiagonalView`, it seems that particular property is now figured from the sign on the angle, rather than with a separate attribute; i.e., whether the angle is positive or negative. Basically, the direction is `diagonalAngle > 0 ? DIRECTION_LEFT : DIRECTION_RIGHT`. They likely just forgot to update the example.

Comment: So I removed the direction and it worked. Thanks for stating the obvious, which I missed

Answer (score 2):

I Just Removed that Attribute(app:shape_diagonal_direction="right"), and it worked for me!
use this code.

```
    <com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:shape_diagonal_angle="6"
        app:shape_diagonal_position="bottom">
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/homepage" />

    </com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>
```

Answer (score 0):

just delete that line, the problem is because of the library version, it simply delete that property.

It must be this:

```
<com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:shape_diagonal_angle="6"
    app:shape_diagonal_position="bottom">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/homepage" />
</com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>
```